# Use NSUserDefaults to access a stored object

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, text, nsuserdefaults

I want to access text saved through NSUserDefaults and display it in a label that has already been defined called "name". My code is below, but it doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks for your help!

```
name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Comment: In certain cases when setting the object, you need to call `-synchronize` to make sure the value gets stored, usually if you are setting the value just before your app exits or something like that, also @diwup is correct, your current method will silently fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be:

```
name.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should register your defaults someway like this: **(this is only necessary if you want to add multiple items!)**

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDict = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MyName", @"defaultName", @"MyAge", @"defaultAge", nil];`
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDict];
```

Now use this assuming you have a label pointer:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[label setText:[defaults stringForKey:@"defaultName"]];
```

Comment: That first part actually is not necessary, that's just a method of adding multiple defaults at one time. The storage method [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:] is quicker if you only have one value to set.

Comment: yes, I added my intention, as it's most common that you want more than one value to be set to default and I was not sure if he set the defaults up correctly.